# Displaying different JSON text on interval

Tags: json

How is it possible here to display next JSON data on intervals(20s for example)?
Here is the code for getting JSON data

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        var data= response.data;

        var output = '';
       for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){ 
         output += ''+data[0].data1+''+data[0].data2+'<br/>';
       }
        document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML = output;
      }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "url.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: @pokeybit That really did not help me that much, If I do that, same JSON data will be collected. I need different(next one) data to be displayed.

Comment: You call a function containing the above code using setInterval, use `url.php?page=1` (increment the page value every call) to output a json header and content, the `xhttp.open("GET", "url.json", true);` doesn't need to reference a file with json extension